# Using multiple columns to create multiple aggregates

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table with 20 columns with 3 values Y, N, I
How do I create a count of each values per field

[image]

```
Select 
    field_1, count(field_1), 
    field_2, count(field_2), 
    field_3, count(field_3),
    field_4, count(field_3)
    ...
    field_20, count(field_20)
FROM table 
Group by field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4... field_20
```

I wanted my results to formatting like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this for the first column

```
       SUM(CASE WHEN field_1 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field_2 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field_3 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field_4 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field_4,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN field_20 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field_20
FROM table
UNION ALL
```

And repeat this code for each one and add from table_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data by using `unnest` over column name - column value pairs and aggregating over column name with `count_if`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(field_1, field_2) AS (
    values  ('Y', 'N'),
        ('N', 'Y'),
        ('Y', 'N'),
        ('N', 'I'),
        ('I', 'N')
)

-- query
select col_name,
       count_if(col_value = 'Y') as Y,
       count_if(col_value = 'N') as N,
       count_if(col_value = 'I') as I
from dataset,
unnest(
    array['field_1', 'field_2'], -- 'field_3', etc.
    array[field_1, field_2] -- 'field_3', etc.
    ) as t(col_name, col_value)
group by col_name;
```

Output:

| col_name | Y | N | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| field_1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| field_2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |